# AsyncPostback Trigger - Textbox value not getting sent back

Tags: c#, asp.net

My UpdatePanel

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
    EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
    runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtName" 
            EventName="TextChanged"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"
           AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtName_TextChanged" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

Why isn't the value of my textbox (txtName) getting sent back to the server when it loses focus? The async postback happens but no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EventName** should be **EventName="TextChanged"**.

**TextChanged** is default for **TextBox** control, so you don't even need to set it.

[AsyncPostBackTrigger.EventName Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.eventname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
    EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
    runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtName" 
            EventName="TextChanged"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"
           AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtName_TextChanged" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = txtName.Text;
}
```

Comment: The value is not coming back still

Comment: @KyleJohnson I tested it, and it worked fine. Create a new ASPX page without mater page. Then paste the above code and test it.